# Laravel 8 File Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to laravel and I have been struggling to validate uploaded files.

Below is the code that handles validation:

```
// (I tried mime, mimes, mimetypes) none of them are validating any of the files correctly.
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'proposal_summary' => 'mimetypes:application/pdf|max:2048',
            'plagiarism_report' => 'mimetypes:pdf,doc,docx,txt|max:2048',
            'final_proposal' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx,txt|max:2048',
        ]);
```

I tested this with PDF, docx and txt files, all without success. I get an error saying the files must be a file of type: pdf, doc, docx, txt. Even though they are. I am sure I am doing something wrong, so any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you require more code or further explanation.

Comment: Try with `'proposal_summary' => 'mimes:application/pdf'`

Comment: Check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-mimes and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-mimetypes; you seem to be mixing and matching the logic slightly. Also, what version of Laravel is this? You have 4, 5 and 8 linked, and they are all pretty different these days.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The version is Laravel 8. The mixing and matching is a result of trying different solutions after 'mimes' was not producing the expected output.

Comment: @HelderDoggo if you read what @TimLewis said, you have to use `mimes` rules for `plagiarism_report` and `final_proposal`, as that accepts `pdf`, `doc`, etc, but `mimetypes` needs the full mime type... also, share what the actual errors is, what field is giving error with what rules....

Comment: Also, is this an AJAX request? Or a simple `<form>` submission? Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? We need more information on your approach :)

Comment: it could be a front-end problem, make sure you have enctype="multipart/form-data" and /or you're using FormData if you're using JavaScript.

Comment: I tried to use `mimes` but it gives error for all 3 fields. The exact error is `<field>must be a file of type pdf, doc...`. It is an AJAX request and the form does have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Apologies, it is only the second time I have posted a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `mimes` validation rule. You can also call the `validate()` method on the Request instead of `Validator::make()` method:

```
// dd(request()->all()); // Use this to debug the request content

$validated = request()->validate([
    'proposal_summary'   => ['mimes:pdf', 'max:2048'],
    'plagiarism_report'  => ['mimes:pdf,doc,docx,txt', 'max:2048'],
    'final_proposal'     => ['mimes:pdf,doc,docx,txt', 'max:2048'],
]);

// dd($validated); // Use this to debug validated content
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-mimes